# How to get value for 0.5^(5000) in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numeric, largenumber

Current I want to calculate the value of `a=0.5**5000`. I know`a` is very small value, but I need use `a` to multiply `b`, where `b = 5000!`, a very large value.

But when I calculate value of   `a=0.5^5000`, the result is 0. Does anyone have a good method to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean by `a = 0.5 * 5000` ??

Comment: @U12-Forward. No, sorry I mean 0.5**5000

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: >>> `pow(a, 1000)`
9.332636185032189e-302

Comment: for `.5 ** 5000` it  is likely return `0.0` because python floats are not able to show that amount of precision (the number is too close to zero for python to be able to distinguish it from 0). The lowest you will get with pure python in `.5 ** 1074`

Comment: You can figure out what the largest power of two is that divides 5000! and then figure out, in a closed form, what power of two remains after multiplying by 0.5\*\*5000. https://www.justquant.com/numbertheory/highest-power-of-a-number-in-a-factorial/. As this is likely an exercise, perhaps the point is to think of ways to compute the answer without pure brute force.

Comment: Do you need `n!/(2**n)`, or will you multiply *that* by another number? There's probably a better way to compute this. For example, `n choose k` is `n!/((n-k)!*k!)`, but nobody computes it like that; you compute it recursively with `((n-1) choose k) + ((n-1) choose (k-1))`.

Comment: Can you please clarify why you need to do this? Surely you aren't interested in the *fixed* value of 5000! * 0.5^5000 but some parameterised formula to compute something practical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the decimal module:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> print(Decimal("0.5") ** 5000)
7.079811261048172892385615159E-1506
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

> I need use `a` to multiply `b`, where `b = 5000!`

I'd just divide 5000! by 2<sup>5000</sup> or shift it:

```
from math import factorial

print(factorial(5000) // 2**5000)
print(factorial(5000) >> 5000)
```

Output:

```
299375336...(more than 14000 digits)...080261230
```

Or as @wim points out, `fractions.Fraction` would be exact:

```
print(Fraction(factorial(5000), 2**5000))
```

Output:

```
958001075...(more than 14000 digits)...568359375/32
```

Which in decimal notation is:

```
299375336...(more than 14000 digits)...080261230.46875
```

So in this case that gives us only five more digits of precision, not much compared to already over 14000. But for example for 5!/2<sup>5</sup> it would be 3.75 instead of 3, quite a big difference. Then again, this small number (if you're using it as well) might be insignificant in what you're doing overall. Which we don't know because you only told us about this tiny part of your attempt to do whatever it is you're actually after.

Comment: The result is not actually an integer, so using `//` loses precision.

Comment: @wim It has 14821 digits of precision. What makes you think that's not enough? It's far more than the other answers provide.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's not enough. When there are factorials are involved it's often some mathematical application where you really want exact arithmetic, so why not use `Fraction(*divmod(factorial(5000), 2**5000))` instead of truncating with `//`.

Comment: @wim Mine is **faaaaar** more accurate than your `Fraction(*divmod(factorial(5000), 2**5000))`. No idea why you're doing `divmod` there :-P. But yes, a correct fraction would be even more precise. Why didn't I? Didn't see a need. And now that the OP accepted a far less precise solution, I still don't.

Comment: Ugh, I was trying to compress it on one line but messed up.  `q, r = divmod(factorial(5000), 2**5000)` then the `q` is your result and the `r` is the remainder, so the exact result is `q + Fraction(r, 2**5000)` (simplifies to `Fraction(15, 32)` interestingly!).

Comment: @wim Could've just done `Fraction(factorial(5000), 2**5000)`. Btw this is now the third or fourth question in two days that says or reminds me of Taylor series or so, where people are approximating numbers. If that's what they're doing, I think my precision is fine. Better than fine.

Comment: Yes, of course, but then it is not demonstrating the lost remainder 15/32  :) 
Anyway I never said the accepted answer was good, I am just pointing out that _this_ answer is actually still losing precision despite working with integer arithmetic. So why not use exact arithmetic when it's just as easy to do so in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative answer using the [mpmath library](https://mpmath.org/):

```py
import mpmath

a = mpmath.power(0.5, 5000)
b = mpmath.factorial(5000)
c = mpmath.fmul(a, b)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

That includes the other calculations that you mentioned.

Output:

```
7.0798112610481728923856151586941e-1506
4.2285779266055435222010642002336e+16325
2.9937533623001661362907254353912e+14820
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Decimal :

```
from decimal import Decimal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Decimal(str(0.5)) ** Decimal(str(5000))
    print(a)

7.079811261048172892385615159E-1506
```

Comment: Using `Decimal` you should *pass a string*, not a `float`. This float *happens* to work correctly, but you shouldn't do that.

Comment: then parse float into string, but Why I shouldn't do that ?

Comment: **No**. Don't do that, *pass a string*. Look what happens to `Decimal(0.1)`. And relying on `str` is relying on an implementation detail

Comment: If you can't convert to string, how you can calcul for dynamic values?

Comment: You must *start* with strings/Decimal.

Comment: Why use ``decimal`` and not ``fractions``? There doesn't seem to be any advantage doing this in base-10.